# error 20430 'No se encontró 'Sub Main' en 'Practica'

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2019

me estoy iniciando en el maravilloso mundo de la programación, rengo un pequeño inconveniente con visual studio 2019, al compilar me arroja el siguiente código de error 20430 'No se encontró 'Sub Main' en 'Practica'
a continuación público mi código (desde ya gracias a todos)

```
Public Class Form1

Private Sub BtnCalcular_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnCalcular.Click
    ' Dimemencionar ls VARIABLES a utilizar
    Dim monto As Integer
    Dim ips As Integer
    Dim sv As Integer
    Dim aux As Integer
    Dim heroes As Integer
    Dim resultado As UInteger

    'Cargar en la variable MONTO, el monto ingresado
    monto = Val(TxtMonto.Text)

    'se debe entregar un mensaje de error, si el monto ingresado es menor a 2.00.000
    If monto < 2000000 Then
        ' calculo de ips y seguro de vida
        ips = monto * 0.1
        TxtIPS.Text = CStr(ips)

        sv = monto * 0.05
        TxtSeguroV.Text = CStr(sv)

        'claculo decunto para heroes
        'dicho calculo debe ser a lo que queda de descontar ips y seguro de vida
        aux = monto - ips - sv
        heroes = monto * 0.03
        TxtHereos.Text = CStr(heroes)

        'calculo del monto a cobrar 
        resultado = monto - aux - heroes
        TxtResultado.Text = CStr(resultado)
    Else
        'mensaje de error por monto incorrecto
        MessageBox.Show("El monto ingresado es incorrecto, ingrese un monto mayoy o igual a 2.000.000")
    End If

End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: porque le podes haber borrado el metodo principal que inicia toda la app, para mirarlo, create otro proyecto y veras la diferencia

Comment: Gracias... voy a probarlo..